# COM Exception with QBXMLRP2

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbxml

I am working on creating a Quick Books Web Connector like desktop application using QBXML. I have been through the programming guide and trying to write the code to communicate with Quick Books.
But I am getting the COM exception at the very first place:

> rp = new RequestProcessor2();

Error is: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {45F5708E-3B43-4FA8-BE7E-A5F1849214CB} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

I have installed the QBSDK13 and found the Interop.QBXMLRP2 in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks

Not sure what else I needed here. The programming guide doesn't really provide much detail on this COM thing.
I searched the registry with that CLSID but its not there. How do I need to register it

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are referencing QBXMLRP2 in your project and make sure you have built your application for Target x86 only.

Comment: Yes I built in x86. Though I added the reference to "Interop.QBXMLRP2.dll" and I believe this is what needs to be added in the project